# nodejs multiple http requests in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make simple feed reader in node and I'm facing a problem with multiple requests in node.js.
For example, I got table with urls something like:

```
urls = [
"http://url1.com/rss.xml",
"http://url2.com",
"http://url3.com"];
```

Now I want to get contents of each url. First idea was to use `for(var i in urls)` but it's not good idea. the best option would be to do it asynchronously but I don't know how to make it.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I got this code:

```
var data = [];
for(var i = 0; i<urls.length; i++){
    http.get(urls[i], function(response){
    console.log('Reponse: ', response.statusCode, ' from url: ', urls[i]);
    var body = '';
    response.on('data', function(chunk){
        body += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
        data.push(body);
    });
}).on('error', function(e){
    console.log('Error: ', e.message);
});
}
```

Problem is that first is call line "http.get..." for each element in loop and after that event response.on('data') is called and after that response.on('end'). It makes mess and I don't know how to handle this.

Comment: What is the question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do not use `for (x in y)` on arrays! It does not do what you think! Use `for (idx=0,len=array.length; idx < len; ++idx){value=array[idx]; ....}`.

Comment: To get contents of each urls asynchronously in one loop

Comment: This is a duplicate question, answered many times on stack overflow.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

By default node `http` requests are asynchronous. You can start them sequentially in your code and call a function that'll start when all requests are done. You can either do it by hand (count the finished vs started request) or use async.js

This is the no-dependency way (error checking omitted):

```
var http = require('http');    
var urls = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.example.com"];
var responses = [];
var completed_requests = 0;

for (i in urls) {
    http.get(urls[i], function(res) {
        responses.push(res);
        completed_requests++;
        if (completed_requests == urls.length) {
            // All download done, process responses array
            console.log(responses);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks, it inspired me to solve this problem just the way you said.

Comment: actually, the way it is right now, it will say it is complete when the last request is send, but NOT when all the request are done. I gave an answer of what I ended up doing to solve this.

Comment: Adrian's comment is very important. Be aware of that this answer **does not** mean that any of those requests **completed**. By this solution, you only ***know*** requests were 'sent' and iteration was over.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "http.get(urls[url]..." or in that case "for (url of urls)"? assuming that urls is an array.

Comment: what if i wanted to perform multiple http requests with arrays and they have to be executed sequentially..I tried async /await to but they are executed parallely...What i mean by sequentially is,after the completion of one array of http requests,it should goto the next array of http requests.Async/await executes all arrays of HTTP requests simultaneously

Answer (score 55):

I know this is an old question, but I think a better solution would be to use JavaScripts `Promise.all()`:

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const urls = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.example.com"];
const promises = urls.map(url => request(url));
Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
    // data = [promise1,promise2]
});
```

Comment: why would it be better? Little explanation would really make it better!

Comment: I like this approach. Much cleaner

Comment: @MdSifatulIslam this uses es6 so it may not be helpful for everyone. It's more concise, efficient, and simpler to digest once you're used to this style of [modern] coding.

Comment: do you know what happens if the response type of those requests are of type `NodeJS.ReadableStream|FileObject|Buffer` as is the case with watson text to speech api response?    are the responses fully "received" and "completed" at the time of the `Promise.all()` callback?  when i try to pipe each readable stream response into a writeable stream within a `forEach()` loop over the promise responses in the callback, i get incomplete files.

Comment: As of Feb 11th 2020, request is fully deprecated. - https://github.com/request/request-promise

Answer (score 28):

You need to check that on `end` (data complete event) has been called the exact number of requests... Here's a working example:

```js
var http = require('http');
var urls = ['http://adrianmejia.com/atom.xml', 'http://twitrss.me/twitter_user_to_rss/?user=amejiarosario'];
var completed_requests = 0;

urls.forEach(function(url) {
  var responses = [];
  http.get(url, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
      responses.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on('end', function(){
      if (completed_requests++ == urls.length - 1) {
        // All downloads are completed
        console.log('body:', responses.join());
      }      
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: How it would work using request module instead of http? I mean is it possible to achive this using request and async modules?

Comment: @Adrian shouldn't var responses = []; be declared outside the forEach instead of inside ?

Comment: @blue-sky no, because I want to keep the response from each link separate. The forEach loop will start with the first link and `data` will push multiple chunks. `end` will display the full response. On the next link, I want to start with an empty `response`, since I already logged out the response.

Comment: Really helpful example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use any promise library with ".all" implementation. I use RSVP library, Its simple enough.

```
var downloadFileList = [url:'http://stuff',dataname:'filename to download']
var ddownload = downloadFileList.map(function(id){
          var dataname = id.dataname;
          var url = id.url;
          return new RSVP.Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
           var stream = fs.createWriteStream(dataname);
            stream.on('close', function() {
            console.log(dataname+' downloaded');
            fulfill();  
            });
          request(url).on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    reject();
  }).pipe(stream);
        });
        });      
        return new RSVP.hashSettled(ddownload);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Promise.allSettled** will not stop at error. It make sure you process all responses, even if some have an error.

```
Promise.allSettled(promises)
 .then((data) => {
// do your stuff here
 })
 .catch((err) => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 4));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be easily solved using closure. Make a function to handle the request and call that function in the loop. Every time the function would be called, it would have it's own lexical scope and using **closure**, it would be able to retain the address of the URL even if the loop ends. And even is the response is in **streams**, closure would handle that stuff too.

```
const request = require("request");

function getTheUrl(data) {
    var options = {
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + data
    }
    return options
}

function consoleTheResult(url) {
    request(url, function (err, res, body) {
        console.log(url);
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    consoleTheResult(getTheUrl(i))
}
```