# Is it possible to remove "data" element from JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I got json from 2 different links and appended them into 1. [code in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34437462/1778674). However, I want to remove the `data` element from it. How would I approach this ?

[image]

Comment: a picture is worth a thousand words they say ... not here - post it as code please

Answer (score 1):

Try to use delete

```
delete(server.events[0].data)
```

Comment: Slightly off-topic. Is this how we remove `data` when we parse JSON ? I mean, do we manually delete `data` every time or is there a better way I don't know about ?

Comment: you mean to say from each event you want to delete data right?

Comment: I mean, every time I call this code `var json = JSON.parse(url/json)`, `var json` has `data` in it. How do you ask for JSON without taking `data`

Comment: You''re gonna need to remove `data` after each `JSON.parse` call. Can't you remove it server side ?

Comment: @EoiFirst, I can, but I thought there might be an easier way using JavaScript. Something like a built in function that take JSON and remove `data`

Comment: @Suhaib Using JSON.parse you cant eliminate specific key from object. you may need some extra code to handle it.

Comment: You could do your own parse function that do `JSON.parse`, remove the `data` and then return the object

Answer (score 1):

You can use the delete keyword like so;

```
delete server.events[0].data;
```

**Updated** answer regarding question in comment;

When you only have to remove a couple of fields then yes, that is the way it is done. You can however also transform the object by remapping it to a new object. This allows to create a new object without the obsolete fields and possibly choosing new names for your keys.
A small example:

```js
var items = {server: {events: [{data: [], paging: {}}]}};
var newEventMapping = items.server.events.map(item => ({
    myPaging: item.paging
}));
console.log(newEventMapping);

items.server.events = newEventMapping;

console.log(items);
```

Comment: thanks, slightly off-topic. Is this how we remove `data` when we parse JSON ? I mean, do we manually delete `data` or is there a better way like npm module?

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeData(obj){
  for(var key in obj){
  if(key == 'data') delete obj[key];
  if(typeof obj[key] == 'object') removeData(obj[key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: The JSON structure doesn't seem to need recursive function.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.