# Use npm request and get an array of data in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

thanks for the help first.

So my problem is: I'm using request in node.js to parse a list o links and I want to get this data in an array then pass to mongoose

```
function running(link,name,title)
{
    try{
    request.get(link,function(error,response,body){
        return some-data
    })
}
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }  
};
```

but if I do this

```
lstPttn1.forEach(function(data){
        //Final link with date pattern
        var lnkFnal = data.site + datReq;
        lst.push(running(lnkFnal,data.nome,data.titulo)))

    });
```

because request is assynchronous it get a empty list, I'm pretty newbie at assynchronous so I tried to find a solution but didn't find anything like with request, how can I make this happen?

Thanks for the help

**EDIT:--------**

So I found this post [Link of Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911429/nodejs-multiple-http-requests-in-loop/19911657#19911657)

and just added this past on my request code.

```
count++     
if(count==lstPttn1.length){                 
console.log(lstFnal)
}
```

Comment: Since you tagged your question [promise], it looks like you actually do have an idea what the solution is. Make `running` return a promise for the data.