# How do I assign my get response data to an array in the order I sent the request

Tags: javascript, arrays, rest, request, response

I have a rest.get request inside a for loop, that is sending around 20 queries (based on data from a previous request that changes the query each time). My problem is that it seems to be running the for loop completely through and then the queries run asynchronously and are responding with the data that returns the quickest instead of consecutively. If I console.log the index of the forloop inside the .end function, it is undefined until the forloop is finished and then it is the final number (even though it is all inside the for loop).  I am trying to save (push to an array) the data in the same order I am sending the request, so I can match the data with the previous get response list that I’m printing out. Is there a way to assign my response data to an array in the order that I am sending the request instead of first come first serve?

```
// this function is being called inside the previous query 
function carData(req, res) {

  var carNameJson = [];
  var resultToJson = [];

  //singleCars.length is defined in a previous query and is an array of car IDs
  for (var index = 0; index < singleCars.length; ++index) {
    //Grab each individual car ID and concatinate it into a Query
    var carNames = singleCars[index];
    var carQuery = "https://queryinfo";
    var finalSingleQuery = "carQuery + carNames";

    // puts the data into an array of JSON objects
    carNameJson = {
      carID: carNames
    };

    // result is a global variable assigned as an empty array
    // it list all the car IDs in a JSON format
    result.push(carNameJson);

    rest
      .get(finalSingleQuery)
      .proxy("http://proxyinfo")
      .end(function(resp) {
        resultToJson = {
          carInfo: resp.body
        };
     // resultInfo is a global variable assigned as an empty array
        resultInfo.push(resultToJson);
        return resultToJson;
      });
  }
}
```

This code all works, but it gives me the data out of order, so I can't match the car information to the list of car IDs. I am new to node, so I may be doing this all wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What about sending a current timestamp with each request, which propogates into the response, and then sort the responses by timestamp.

Comment: how about returning the ID in the response so you can match them up?

Comment: @ADyson How would I return the ID in the response? Every time I try to access the variables (even global) by passing them through the current request from the previous response, I get undefined.

Comment: @Bango Do you know the best way to access that? I saw that someone put this, but I tried `(res.header('Date', new Date()))` and it returned a ton of information.

Comment: not sure what you mean. I'm not entirely familiar with the syntax and tools you're using here, but as a general point, surely in order to query some car data, you have to pass the IDs of the required cars into your request? Therefore it should be possible to include those car IDs in the resulting response alongside the rest of the data, in order to provide continuity. Since these requests are asynchronous that is going to be the easiest way to do it. As you've discovered, you can't guarantee the order the results will be returned in.

Comment: Your other option is to refactor it so that you make one request containing 20 values, the responses to which are fetched all in one array in a single response, and in the precise order you would like them to be. Then you have 1) less requests going backwards and forwards, and 2) less problems with asynchronous code.

Comment: Nevermind timestamps... Looks to me like you're not using the req variable at all. That variable is your request, and it could potentially contain important data, such as an ID, which you could then return in a JSON response alongside other data.  It's weird to me that you aren't using the req variable, and are just returning the same thing with every request.

Comment: @ADyson Unfortunately I do not have control over the data that I get back from the query (if that is what you are saying). It only gives the Information about whatever carID is passed in. I have tried adding the carIDs as part of my function parameters, but regardless of what I try, they don't seem to be accessible inside the .end part of the response.

Comment: @ADyson Would that make them run synchronously? I actually need them to run asynchronously (I need the data asap on a page load) but I need it in order. lol :(

Comment: @Bango That sounds great. Could you elaborate on how I would return an ID with each request?

Comment: It would still make the request asynchronous, but it would just be one request fetching all of the data. And should be quicker than 20 requests (because each HTTP request has an overhead cost to it of making the connection). But if you're saying you've got no control over the backend, then unless there is another method you can call to fetch car data in bulk (instead of one car at a time like it seems you do now) then you might be a bit stuck.

Comment: @ADyson does this look similar to the solution you are mentioning - would this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911429/nodejs-multiple-http-requests-in-loop

Comment: Does `var finalSingleQuery = "carQuery + carNames"` even work? Should that not be without the double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the index variable to target where to store the response. For that you must make sure the `index` variable is local to the `for` body, which you can achieve with `let` (instead of `var`):

```
for (let index = 0; index < singleCars.length; ++index) {

    // ...

    // store directly at the correct index:
    resultInfo[index] = resultToJson;
```

You might also be interested to know when you have all results. This you can do with this condition, just after the assignment to `resultInfo[index]`:

```
    if (resultInfo.filter(Object).length === singleCars.length) {
        // maybe call a callback here.
    }
```

Comment: I tried ` if (resultInfo.filter(Number).length === singleCars.length) {
        // maybe call a callback here.
    }` but resultInfo.filter(Number).length always returns 0.

Comment: Good you found a way! I updated with `Object` instead of `Number`, but `Object.keys` works fine too.

Answer (score 1):

You're performing restful response inside of a for loop. Instead, consider building a complete JSON object filled with all the data the client will need (in other words, send it all as 1 big response, instead of lots of little responses).

Use the for loop to build the JSON, then outside of the loop, perform your 1-time restful response.

That way you don't have to worry about the data coming through out of order, and the response is complete and not missing important information like index.

Comment: Would this make it synchronous? I need it to run all 20 request simultaneously.

Comment: Why is there a need for 20 requests as opposed to 1 request. No, it's still asynchronous. The page doesn't have to reload to get new data.

Comment: The carID changes on each request, so wouldn't it have to be a different request each time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19911657/6416639 (switching the url variable out with the JSON you mentioned) is this what you are referring to?

Comment: The thing is, you're sending 20 responses all at once. Rather than send 20 responses all at once, send 1 response 1 time, and have it contain 20 different things.

Comment: It is 20 different queries, that each return one specific and unique line of data. It's not one Query, that I can grab all 20 responses from.