# Request multiple url for web scraping

Tags: node.js, request

I have this simple script:

```
request ({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.link1.org/'
    url: 'https://link2.net/'
}, function(err, response, body) {
//do stuff
}
```

It works fine with single url but how could i add another? I need it to get both urls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodejs multiple http requests in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911429/nodejs-multiple-http-requests-in-loop)

Comment: You have to do it as multiple requests. If you're not worried about 'callback hell' you could nest one request in the other's callback, but the popular thing to do is to promisify your requests and use `Promise.all`.