# Download a file from web using Node js and loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to download multiple files from the web using this code:

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var http = require('http');
    var request = require('request');

    var file;
    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
         //CHECK IF REMOTE FILE EXISTS
         request('http://webaddress.com/filename' + i + '.jar', function (err, resp) {

         //IF EXISTS DO
         if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
             //DOWNLOAD DATA AND CREATE A NEW .JAR FILE
             file = fs.createWriteStream('D:\\filename' + i + '.jar');
             http.get('http://webaddress.com/filename' + i + '.jar', function(response) {
                  response.pipe(file);
                  file.on('finish', function() {
                      file.close();
                  });
             });
         }

         //FILE DOES NOT EXIST
         });
     }
```

The result I want is: multiple files downloaded with filenames *filename1-5.jar*. The result I am getting is just 1 file with filename *filename5.jar* (or the last value of the i var in the loop). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your request is asynchronous and it will execute only after your loop finishes hence the `5` from the filename.

Comment: I suspected so. Thanks. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: See this answer, it can help you solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/19911657/8221063

Comment: Thanks @LucasDuarte I'll check it out.

Comment: @lupu51nfactumN778, I have added an answer for you.

Answer (score 3):

Like @Ionut said your requests are async so you need to wait for it

```
let fs = require('fs');
let request = require('request');

let download = (uri, filename) => {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        request.head(uri, function(err, res) {

            if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', resolve);
            } else {
                reject(res.statusCode);
            }
        });
    });
};

let promises = [];

for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    promises.push(download('http://webaddress.com/filename' + i + '.jar', 'D:\\filename' + i + '.jar'));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    process.exit(0);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your request is asynchronous and it will execute only after your loop finishes hence the `5` from the filename. A solution for this is to threat your code separately by creating a new function and call it inside the loop:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');

var file;

function customRequest(i){

  //CHECK IF REMOTE FILE EXISTS
  return request('http://webaddress.com/filename' + i + '.jar', function(err, resp) {

    //IF EXISTS DO
    if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
      //DOWNLOAD DATA AND CREATE A NEW .JAR FILE
      file = fs.createWriteStream('D:\\filename' + i + '.jar');
      http.get('http://webaddress.com/filename' + i + '.jar', function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', function() {
          file.close();
        });
      });
    }

    //FILE DOES NOT EXIST
  });

}

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
   customRequest(i)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code does make 5 separate files. The issue I have now is that all data goes to just 1 random file, others are empty. Could this be that the function is executed too fast? I tried setTimeout without much luck.