# Wait for response inside for loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have below code which is making an third party api call using `request` npm

```
const array = []
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  request('api_call', function(err, res) {
    array.push(res)
  })
}
console.log(array)
```

But didn't get anything in the array.

Can someone please help how can I wait for all the 10 api calls?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @tkausl I have the query inside the for loop here. That the main problem

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911429/nodejs-multiple-http-requests-in-loop

Comment: try reading documentation first https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request()` is non-blocking and asynchronous.  So your `for` loop runs to the end, before ANY of your `request()` calls have completed.  There are many ways to do this, but the best way I know of is to use promises and `Promise.all()`:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const promises = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  promises.push(rp('api_call'));
}
Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
   console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

request-promise is a promisified version of the request library (returns a promise instead of using a plain callback).  This code accumulates promises into an array and then uses `Promise.all()` to tell us when all the promises have resolved (e.g. all the requests are done).  The results are then presented to us in order in the `results` array.

This method run all your requests in parallel.

---

If you want to run them in sequence instead of in parallel, you can use `async/await` to make the `for` loop pause for each result before continuing.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

async function myFunc() {
    const results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let r = await rp('api_call');
        results.push(r);
    }
    return results;
}


myFunc().then(results => {
   console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

If you're actually not just sending the same request 10 times, but are actually iterating an array to make the 10 api calls, then you'd probably use `.map()` or something like that.

Comment: Great answer by a great man. Thank you very much for such long winded explanation.

Comment: Could you please let me know what is **plain callback**?

Comment: @DarkKnight - The `function(err, res) {}` in your original code is a plain callback.